# Creating a numpy array from a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I noticed the following behaviour exhibited by numpy arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = {1,2,3}
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> np.array(l)
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.array(s)
array({1, 2, 3}, dtype=object)
>>> np.array(l, dtype='int')
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.array(l, dtype='int').dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> np.array(s, dtype='int')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

There are 2 things to notice:

1. Creating an array from a set results in the array `dtype` being `object`
2. Trying to specify dtype results in an error which suggests that the
   set is being treated as a single element rather than an iterable.

What am I missing - I don't fully understand which bit of python I'm overlooking. Set is a mutable object much like a list is.

EDIT: tuples work fine:

```
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> np.array(t)
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.array(t).dtype
dtype('int64')
```

Comment: Can you just convert the set to a list? np.array(list(s), dtype='int')

Comment: Unlike lists, sets have no order, so `np.array` cannot infer which element comes before or after the others. This is why the set ends up being treated as a single element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `array` factory works best with [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) objects which a set is not. If you do not care about the order of elements and know they are all ints or convertible to int, then you can use `np.fromiter`

```
np.fromiter({1,2,3},int,3)
# array([1, 2, 3])
```

The second (dtype) argument is mandatory; the last (count) argument is optional, providing it can improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the syntax of using curly brackets, a `set` are more closely related to a `dict` than to a `list`. You can solve it very simply by turning the set into a `list` or `tuple` before converting to an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = {1,2,3}
>>> np.array(s)
array({1, 2, 3}, dtype=object)
>>> np.array(list(s))
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.array(tuple(s))
array([1, 2, 3])
```

However this might be too inefficient for large sets, because the `list` or `tuple` functions have to run through the whole `set` before even starting the creation of the array. A better method would be to use the `set` as an iterator:

```
>>> np.fromiter(s, int)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

The [np.array documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) says that the `object` argument must be "an array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose `__array__` method returns an array, **or any (nested) sequence**" (emphasis added).

A set is not a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence). Specifically, sets are unordered and do not support the `__getitem__` method. Hence you cannot create an array from a set like you trying to with the list.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy expects the argument to be a list, it doesn't understand the set type so it creates an object array (this would be the same if you passed any other non sequence object). You can create a numpy array with a set by first converting the set to a list `numpy.array(list(my_set))`. Hope this helps.